# Ubuntu Synology DiskStation

Tags: networking, samba, nas

I have a Synology DiskStation DS1513+ NAS (IP: 192.168.2.112) and a desktop PC (192.168.2.132). The desktop is a dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. I can mount, ping, access the NAS using Windows just fine using SMB.

When I try to access it in Ubuntu however, I can see the NAS in the file browser (as a network share [smb and afp] as well as in the WORKGROUP), but when I click it it just times out. Also I cannot ping the NAS's IP (it just does nothing). A direct connection using the connect to server or command line `mount` does not work either. I do not mount the NAS via fstab, but only manually on demand.

The network settings for both Windows and Ubuntu is identical (IP, Subnet, etc.)

Any ideas how to debug this?

Comment: Are you mounting the NAS is your fstab file? Please [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: I've edited my post. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I would try mounting the NAS in your fstab. I can't think of a reason not to. I have the Synology DS220j and it works perfectly in 18.04 using //<ip_address>/<share_name> <mount_point> cifs username=<username>,password=<password>,rw,uid=1000,gid=500

Comment: The question is more: why can't I even ping the NAS?

Comment: what command are you using to ping the nas. In my case, I can do it wither by using the ip address or the name you have given it (in my case ping synonas.local)

Comment: ping 192.168.2.112

Comment: have you changed the name of your NAS? if not try ping synology.local

Comment: yes, sadly it does not help...

Comment: is Windows booting in UEFI mode? If so, it might not be releasing it to make it available to Ubuntu. Try completely exiting from Windows before botting into Ubuntu.

Comment: It might not release what exactly? And what do you mean by "completly exiting". I need to reboot anyway. Windows is using SMB/CIFS for mounting and ubuntu NFS.

Comment: https://www.dummies.com/computers/operating-systems/windows-10/how-to-shut-down-a-computer-running-windows-10/